# Java Swing - How to synchronize ArrayLists

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, synchronized

I'm trying to acsess a single list across two different threads. Originally, I was using a for loop, as shown here:

```
for (int i = 0; i<fighterList.size(); i++) {
    if (fighterList.get(i).isDestroyed() == true) fighterList.remove(i);
}
```

I was informed however, that I would have to synchronize the threads. I don't quite understand how to do this, and more importantly how it works. The resources I've consulted thus far seem to point to two different ways to do this:

```
synchronized(fighterList) {
    for (Object o : fighterList) {
        o.doSomeMethod();
    }
}
```

or

```
Iterator<Fighter> iterator = fighter.iterator(); 
while (iterator.hasNext())
    if (iterator.next().returnSomething() == false) iterator.next().doSomeMethod();
}
```

Neither of these seem to work, however. What is the 'correct' way to do this, and is there some better documentation available?

Comment: "Neither of these seem to work" is not problem description. You need to describe behaviour you want to achieve and what you get instead. Also include [short but full code which will let us reproduce your problem](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Even without having multiple threads accessing `fighterList`, the first example will fail as it modifies the list while iterating over it which is prohibited!

Comment: You could wrap in a `synchronized` wrapper, see [`Collections.synchronizedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List))

Comment: @MadProgrammer If I remember correctly `synchronizedList` makes single operations atomic (add, contains, remove,...) so OP would also need to provide separate synchronization for set of these operations. Depending on what OP really wants to achieve CopyOnWriteArrayList could be also an option. Anyway to answer this question we (or at least I) would need some more informations.

Comment: @Pshemo Yea for lack of context ;) - Also, depending on the circumstances, it might be better to synchronize the operations (the methods been called)...but context is king ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer can we talk again? plz

Comment: @KickButtowski Sure, open a chat ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer       http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65552/madandi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you usually synchronize when you want a thread-safe code,
meaning while this thread is getting inside the cpu no other threads
will try to get there as well, this is also called "Acquiring a lock on an object",
"getting the lock","locking on the object" or "synchronizing on the object"
 and of course you should always remember that nothing is guaranteed as java designers
often states..
anyhow in order to run a thread and synchronized it the class that contains the thread
should do one of the two:
1. Extend the Thread class
or
2. implement the Runnable interface.
 this class should also override an abstract method defined both in the Thread class
and in the Runnable interface called "public void run(){}",
that actually functions as the "main" class of the thread.

lets work it out a bit. it is much easier than it sounds:

```
class ThreadPractice implements Runnable{

 @override   //This annotation denotes that it overrides an abstract method from
             // the Runnable interface.
     public void run(){ // We've promised

      coutingStuff() ; // Calling the synchronized method from the run() method.

         }

      public void synchronized coutingStuff(){// now this is a synchronized method...

              for(int i=0; i<100; i++){// Creating a for loop that counts from 0 to 99...

               System.out.println("this is the "+i+" time that this loop runs");

                // Now, putting the thread to sleep for 1 second:


               try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                     }catch(InterruptedException iex){

                         System.out.println(iex.getMessage());
                      }
               }// End for loop
       }// End public void synchronized coutingStuff(){....


          public static void main(String[] args){

             //Now creating a thread object:

             Runnable rnb = new ThreadPractice();
              Thread count = new Thread(rnb);
                 count.start(); // starts the thread that contains
                                 // the synchronized method.

                }// End main



        }// End of class ThreadPractice
```

I would warmly suggest you to go over the chapter about threads
in the KS&BB guide where you can download here:
http://firozstar.tripod.com/_darksiderg.pdf

Comment: But isn't the `synchronized` method locked based on the instance of the class?